# Global array returns empty despite having an element

Tags: python

I have what might be a quite simple problem, but I still cannot solve it.

I have the following code:

```
list_of_conditions = []  
def function_1():  
    time.sleep(60)  
    global list_of_conditions
    condition=list_of_conditions.pop()  
    condition.notify()  
    print("F1: Done")

def function_2():
    condition = Condition()  
    global list_of_conditions
    list_of_conditions.append(condition)
    with condition:  
       p1=Process(target=function_1, daemon=True)  
       p1.start()  
       condition.wait()
       print("Finished")
```

I think it is quite clear what I want to accomplish with the condition, but I have the problem that the *global array* is not working. I keep getting the error message:

```
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

I dont get it why the list is empty even though I have declare it as global.

Comment: Because you're using Multiprocessing. Processes do *not* share state.  You have to share it yourself.  In this instance you can just pass it in when you start function_1: there's no reason for global state. If the logic is more complicated, do proper producer/consumer with a queue.

Comment: Quick aside: the `global` statement is entirely unnecessary here.  You don't need `global` to refer to a global variable.  You only need it if you are going to assign to it.  Since you only call functions on `list_of_conditions` you're only referring to it.

Comment: To underline @StevenRumbalski's point: appending to (and popping from) a list is *not* the same as *binding a name to a new object*, which is what happens when you do something like `global x; x += 1`: in this case the global name 'x' is set up to point to the number 1 greater than x.  Had you used `+=[condition]` you *would* have needed global (in `function_2`).  Modifying the *contents* of a mutable is not the same as re-assigning the *name* to point to a *new* object, even if the end result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I dont get it why the list is empty

Because you're using Multiprocessing. Processes do *not* share mutable state: each Process starts with a blank slate, i.e. it sees the module as it was at intial evaluation.  Sharing mutable state in multithreading/multiprocessing paradigms is problematic: what if two threads try to modify the same state?

Thus if you want to share state, you have to do it explicitly.  In this instance you could use a [queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue), and set up a pool of consumers waiting for `Condition()`s to be sent them down the queue.

However if the logic as presented here is all that goes on, just modify `function_1` to take the `Condition()` as an argument, and pass it through when you start the process:

```py
def handle_condition(condition: Condition):
    ...

def call_handler():
    condition = Condition()
    # note that args is a tuple
    Process(target=handle_condition, args=(condition,)).start()
```

With that said, your current logic doesn't make much sense---if you're going to stop and wait for every process to run every time, why not just process in the same thread?

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. That solved one problem, but another one appeared :D If you have time, please take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74222512/condition-objects-should-only-be-shared-between-processes-through-inheritance